# Serialize property that throws NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Is there any way to serialize objects of the following class and somehow ignore the exception being thrown?

```
public class HardToSerialize
{
  public string IAmNotTheProblem { get; set; }
  public string ButIAm { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
}
```

Not suprisingly Newtonsoft throws an error when it tries to serialize the value of the `ButIAm` property.

I don't have access to the class so I can't decorate it with any attributes.

Clarification: I want this to work for **any** object that has properties that throws a NotImplementedException. The `HardToSerialize` class is just one example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me. Is there any major problems doing it like this?

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Error += (o, args) => {
    if(args.ErrorContext.Error.InnerException is NotImplementedException)
        args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
};

var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go for a *surrogate* class and a custom `JsonConverter` :

```
public class HardToSerializeSurrogate
{
    public string IAmNotTheProblem { get; set; }
    public string ButIAm { get; set; }
}

public class HardToSerializeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(HardToSerialize);
    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var item = (HardToSerialize)value;

        // fill the surrogate with the values of the original object
        var surrogate = new HardToSerializeSurrogate();
        surrogate.IAmNotTheProblem = item.IAmNotTheProblem;

        serializer.Serialize(writer, surrogate);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var hardToSerialize = new HardToSerialize() { IAmNotTheProblem = "Foo" };
    var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hardToSerialize, 
                                        new HardToSerializeConverter());
}
```

Of course implementing a custom `JsonConverter` is really worth if you must serialize a list of `HardToSerialize` objects, or an object that contains this type.
On the other hand, if you just want to serialize one `HardToSerialize` object each time, just create a surrogate copy of the object and serialize that without implementing a custom `JsonConverter`.

Comment: I want this to work for any object that might have a property that throws NotImplementedException. I have updated the question.

Comment: @JesperPalm: Classes with not-implemented properties should be the exception not the rule. I'd go with surrogates for each of them, because it gives you more control on classes you want and don't want to support. Not to mention to the fact that handling Error event you will probably get worse performances since it raises and catches exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround would be to create another object from `EasyToSerialize` and then serialize it.

```
[Serializable]
public class EasyToSerialize
{
    public string IAmNotTheProblem { get; set; }

    // other serializable properties
}


HardToSerialize x = ...;

var foo2 = new EasyToSerialize {
    IAmNotTheProblem = x.IAmNotTheProblem
    // other properties here
};
```